# Finding the expected value of a function of binormal variables

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

```
ExpectedValue[ex*en, BinormalDistribution[0], {ex, en}]
```

The above is what I would like to calculate (the answer to which should obviously be zero): The expected value of the product of two stochastic variables drawn from a binormal distribution with correlation coefficient = 0.

Yet when I hit shift-return, I don't get an answer.

Please help!
Thanks
Oliver

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the documentation for `ExpectedValue`, you'll see that `Expectation` supersedes it as of version 8.

```
Expectation[ex*en, {ex, en} \[Distributed] BinormalDistribution[0]]
```

> 0